# Which units does a diff_drive_controller output?

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller, ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 with a physical robot.

I am writing the code that interfaces the diff_drive_controller to my physical robot's hardware. I understand that the data the diff_drive_controller takes in is geometry_msgs::Twist (and only uses angular Z, and linear X) which it then converts to velocity commands for each one of the two wheels (the joints specified in the yaml file). My question is: what is the output from diff_drive_controller for each wheel (ex: radians/second, or meters/second, rotations/second, or something else)?

I know how to turn my wheels using code, and now I need to figure out what data I am about to start receiving from the controller. This will allow me to make sure the wheels do exactly what the diff_drive_controller is requesting.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311686/which-units-does-a-diff_drive_controller-output?/) by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2018-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is a duplicate of #q242766.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-30**:
And see my answer to your #q307520 as well.

**Comment by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on 2018-12-30**:
@gvdhoorn thank you, and sorry about missing that information in your answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-31**:
No need to apologise.